# React js using hooks useState infinite loop rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to update my component current state on result by using custom hook but when i update it showing me infinite loop rendering. by using useState() hook. I am new to react hooks.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useReducer, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import getAllFaqs from './faqQuery.graphql';
import { useFaq } from '../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaq';

const Faq = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  const talonProps = useFaq({
    query: getAllFaqs
  });
  const { data, error, loading } = talonProps;
  setState({data})

  console.log("Thank data", state)
  return (<div>its Working</div>);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `setState({data})` everytime your component loads. Try putting the `setState` inside a `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
setState({ data })
}, [data])
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont setState in the functional component directly. Use onCompleted event:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useReducer, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import getAllFaqs from './faqQuery.graphql';
import { useFaq } from '../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaq';

const Faq = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  const talonProps = useFaq({
    query: getAllFaqs,
    onCompleted: ({ data, error, loading }) => setState({data})
  });

  console.log("Thank data", state)
  return (
    <div>its Working</div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following code in a useEffect hook:

```
const talonProps = useFaq({
  query: getAllFaqs
});
const { data, error, loading } = talonProps;
setState({data})
```

That would look like:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useReducer, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import getAllFaqs from './faqQuery.graphql';
import { useFaq } from '../../peregrine/talons/Faq/useFaq';

const Faq = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const talonProps = useFaq({
      query: getAllFaqs
    });
     const { data, error, loading } = talonProps;
     setState({data})
     console.log("Thank data", state)
  }, [])

  return (<div>its Working</div>);
};
```

What's happening is every time the component renders, it calls your query and sets state, causing the component to re-render again, which calls your query and sets state, causing the component to re-render again ... Using useEffect with the second parameter being an empty array will make your component call your query when the component first renders and set state only once.